# Assign multiple keyboard shortcuts for one action

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I've been wondering how can I assign to multiple keyboard shortcuts to do the same action?
More specifically, I want to be able to change my volume with both my headset buttons and my keyboard.

I'm able to change the volume with just one at the time: with the one I define in the 'Keyboard shortcuts' application.
Is there any way?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/292494/multiple-keyboard-shortcuts-for-same-command

Answer (score 7):

You can assign multiple keyboard shortcuts (keybindings) for the same command using `gsettings` command line.

One important thing to know is that Ubuntu 18.04 Settings GUI only shows the first keybinding for a command, so if you have multiple keybindings for a command, the others won't appear in Settings. You can use `gsettings` to all the keybindings.

Let's say I want to add another keybinding for "Switch to Workspace 1". The default for me was `Super+Home`, but I want to add a second keybinding `Ctrl+1`.

```bsh
# list all keybindings
gsettings list-recursively | grep -e org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | sort 

# confirm no other keybinding conflicts
gsettings list-recursively | grep '<Control>1'

# set multiple keybindings for "Switch to Workspace 1"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>Home', '<Control>1']"

# confirm value is set correctly
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1
```

Now you can use either `Super+Home` or `Control+1` to Switch to Workspace 1. Remember, you will only see the first one `Super+Home` in the Settings GUI, but it will work!

Comment: This only works with the window manager hotkeys, not media keys which is what the user was looking for.  Unfortunately media-keys only accept strings, not arrays.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with the Unity desktop.  Only the first keybinding in the list seems to be recognized.

Comment: This method worked (through `dconf-editor`), I could add second shortcuts for media commands (Arch Linux).

Answer (score 5):

I do just that with *Custom Shortcuts*:

[image: screenshot of keyboard shortcuts settings]

I use `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioLowerVolume` (and `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`) command instead of `amixer set 'Master' 10%+`. The only difference/downside I notice is that even *Repeat Keys* on *Typing* tab is set this doesn't apply **to this** custom shortcut.

However, I wasn't able to do some things like use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to turn off my screen (`xset dpms force standby`). It doesn't detect it as a shortcut event.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use xmodmap to reassign the buttons on your headset to the same as you use for your keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but now I need to know what is the default action of 'Audio raise/lower volume', from the Keyboard shortcuts application. Because, when I use my own command 'amixer channel set opt', it raises/lowers the MBO sound card, while I'm listening with my headset.

Comment: @ksemeks : the actions are : `amixer set Master 10%+` to raise the volume `amixer set Master 10%-` to decrease the volume. To get the gauge notification, you could use `notify-send`, but I am not sure how to set the gauge

Comment: @danjjl: well, that's why I'm trying to find the exact action of the Volume up/down, from Setting->Keyboard->Shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

**update for ubuntu 20**

---

have to say those days, `dconf-editor` is very easy to use, really nice.

### 0. preview

[image: workspace up]

[image: workspace down]

### 1. location input

folder too deep ? copy & paste location.

- click title bar 
  or
- <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>
  or
- <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>
  to active localtion bar input:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-up
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-down
```

[image: dconf_location]

### 2. search in folder

many items in folder? search it.

NOTICE: this is different with <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>

[image: search_0]

search result:

[image: search_1]

### 3. bookmark

mark the location you often use.

[image: bookmark]

### 4. changes

Before applying the modifications,
It even intimately shows the difference.

[image: changes]

### 5. default value

you can use `default value`,
and keep your changes in setting (but not effective )

//Refer the previous img.

---

It's awesome, perfect user experience