# Sometimes custom hotkey does not work

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Sometimes after a while custom hotkey does not work and I should logout and log in.

Is there any other way to fix it?

Why this problem happened?

Comment: What is it that the hotkey combination should do?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have this problem for all hotkeys `Alt+Ctl+/` open a ssh connection or  `Alt+Ctl+.` for xsel. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem on some logins. However, I can't open the terminal using the default `Ctrl+Alt+T`, too.

Comment: So, any way to fix that?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller I have no longer this issue, probably an update fixed it.

Comment: [Here using Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/873116/349837), Super+Shift+Down mapped to `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioLowerVolume` and since last month **sometimes** doesn't work, sometimes does work and don't work the _down_ counterpart. Usually work both.